# Is there any way to connect to/control Mac OS without display output?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, google-chrome, remote-desktop, gpu

I have a 2009 Mac Pro with a Nvidia 1060 and bootcamped to run Windows.

Nvidia drivers are installed on Windows and no issues with display output, all works fine. In the past when I've then tried to boot up into Mac OS I don't get any display output and I've had to connect via Chrome Remote Desktop to boot back into Windows. Recently there have been some changes to Chrome Remote Desktop and my Mac OS install is marked as an invalid configuration - prompting concerns that I won't be able to remote in to reboot the machine back into windows.

Looking for suggestions on either a) how I can remote in and manually boot into windows if required or b) how to resolve a Chrome Remote Desktop "invalid configuration"

Comment: When you boot into the Mac side, does it boot successfully, but you just cannot see anything? Do you happen to have Remote Login (aka "ssh") enabled on the Mac side of things? Have you tried "Safe Boot" for the Mac?

Comment: Also just to make sure, you're on High Sierra or lower, correct?

Comment: @TJLuoma I don't have SSH enabled and not tried safe boot.

Comment: @JMY1000 Yeah, that's correct.